# how to work with local tmp files in an Nodejs API?

Tags: node.js, express

I am currently making a little API which returns jsons according to an input. This API needs to run some local programs on the server and also needs to place some temporary files. It all works if I ask the API once a time and just with one "user".

The problem is, that I only have one temp folder to store the temporary files.so whenever there are multiple API queries, the tmp folder screws up - the data in there mixes up.

What would be a good way to have an API using temp files - and still keep it working if every run needs its own temp data?

The current process is:

```
server/api/getGeometry?lat=52.5167776&lon=13.4092091&bboxSize=2000&output=glb
```

- server queries zips according to lat/lon
- unpacks
- converts
- does voodoo
- generates json
- sends back the json
- cleans up the tmp folder

next run same story...
so every time the same tmp folder, I guess it's not the way to go.

Thanks a lot for ideas!

Comment: If I'm following correctly, the files going into the temp folder are the contents of zip files? if that's the case and you're the one dictating the unzip process, unzip them into a subdirectory of the temp folder. Then only delete the subfolder once the process is finished and not the entire tmp directory? or maybe move the files to the cloud (s3 or some other blob storage) in a raw format and skip the zipping process entirely?

Comment: yes youre correct - thats my plan! currently i think about putting everythin inside of a new folder with a time stamp for example.

Comment: not using a time stamp. I use `uuidv4()` for better reliability